# Recognise .tcc files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I recently stumbled over the file format .tcc which from what I understand is a way to separate the interface from the implementation when writing template classes in c++

However, Visual Studio does not seem to recognize this format in the way that it does not do any "pretty printing", that will say making keywords blue, types light blue etc.

Is there a way to make visual studio recognize this format and also make intellisense available for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. From the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
2. Expand **Text Editor** nodes and select **File Extension**.
3. Input “**tcc**” in the **Extension** textbox, and Select **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012** from the Editor list, click **Apply** and then click **Ok**.

---

**Edit:** In reply to your comment, see [this piece of documentation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165326%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in regard to setting Editor options.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does all the pretty printing and enabled intellisense but it does not highlight(red underline) when I do typos and write code that will be errors. Any way to turn this on as well?